# Sort List by CreatedDate

Tags: apex, soql, list, wrapper-class, sort

I have a following wrapper class:

```
public  with sharing class HistoryRecordWrapper {
Id CreatedById;
Datetime CreatedDate;
Object Field;
Object NewValue;
Object OldValue;

public HistoryRecordWrapper(AccountHistory accHistory) {
    CreatedById = accHistory.CreatedById;
    CreatedDate = accHistory.CreatedDate;
    Field = accHistory.Field;
    if(accHistory.NewValue != null || accHistory.NewValue != '') {
        NewValue = accHistory.NewValue;
    }
    if(accHistory.OldValue != null || accHistory.OldValue != '') {
        OldValue =  accHistory.OldValue;
    }
}

public HistoryRecordWrapper(ContactHistory conHistory) {
    CreatedById = conHistory.CreatedById;
    CreatedDate = conHistory.CreatedDate;
    Field = conHistory.Field;
    if(conHistory.NewValue != null || conHistory.NewValue != '') {
        NewValue =  conHistory.NewValue;
    }
    if(conHistory.OldValue != null || conHistory.OldValue != '') {
        OldValue = conHistory.OldValue;
    }
}
```

}

Also, I have another class that can combine contact and account history records and that returns list of combined history records.

```
public with sharing class HistoryRecordsHandler {

public static List<HistoryRecordWrapper> getAccountAndContactHistoryRecords(Id accId) {
    List<HistoryRecordWrapper> hrws = new List<HistoryRecordWrapper>();

    List<AccountHistory> accHis = [SELECT AccountId, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Field, DataType, IsDeleted, NewValue, OldValue FROM AccountHistory WHERE AccountId = :accId];
    List<ContactHistory> conHis = [
        SELECT ContactId, CreatedById, CreatedDate, Field, DataType, IsDeleted, NewValue, OldValue
        FROM ContactHistory
        WHERE Contact.AccountId = :accId
    ];
    
    if (!conHis.isEmpty()) {
        for (ContactHistory conHi : conHis) {
            HistoryRecordWrapper crs = new HistoryRecordWrapper(conHi);
            hrws.add(crs);
        }
    }

    if (!accHis.isEmpty()) {
        for (AccountHistory accHi : accHis) {
            HistoryRecordWrapper hrs = new HistoryRecordWrapper(accHi);
            hrws.add(hrs);
        }
    }

    return hrws;
}
```

}

How can I sort hrws list based on CreatedDate (record that got edited last should be first in the list)?

Comment: What would the code look like in this case?

Comment: your wrapper class shouldn't have separate constructors by sobjecttype; just have a single constructor that accepts SObjectType